# What is the most efficient way to iterate through an SQL relationship when formatting a JSON response?

Tags: python, sql, api, sqlalchemy

I noticed a bottleneck in an api I worked on recently, it relates to how the json response is formatted, specifically with having to iterate through the relationship to format the response. The database query itself takes ~1s while the formatting takes in excess of 20s for a sample size of 500 entries.

## query

```
data = Item.query.limit(500).all()
```

## formatting

```
data = [{
        'attributes': {
            'id': item.id,
            [...]
            'approved': item.approved,
        }
        'sizes': [{
            'size': size.size,
            'size_fr': size.size_fr,
            'quantity': size.quantity,
            'available': size.available,
            'out_of_order': size.out_of_order
        } for size in item.sizes],
        'tags': [{
            'tag': tag.tag,
            'tag_fr': tag.tag_fr,
            'id': tag.id
        } for tag in item.tags],
        'images': [{
            'url': image.url,
            'primary': image.primary,
            'background_removed': image.background_removed,
            'id': image.id
        } for image in item.images],
    } for item in data]
```

The issue is obviously due to iterating over the relationships on each iteration of the data collection, but I'm not sure how else to process the data.

I'm assuming there has to be a more efficient way to process and format the data.

Comment: what about using eager loading, since you seem to need all the relationships fetched.

Comment: Yup, that just about did it, changing the loading from dynamic to joined brought it down to 3s and changing it to subquery decreased it to 1s. If you want to submit the comment as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.